# update xcode and ios

Tags: xcode, ios14

ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 13.2 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later, included in Xcode 11 or later. Further, starting April 26, 2021 iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 14 SDK or later, included in Xcode 12 or later.

My current xcode version is 11.3 I want to update it to xcode 12 and iOS 14.

Is there any way to update xcode without downloading manually?

Comment: Install the newer versions, then try to build your project and see where it complains, then fix that and check if everything still works

Comment: @dandan78 I wanted to know how to update not download and install new file. I heard there is a way  to update via terminal instead download and install manually